# Abrir Url con UIImage

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode

Utilizar una imagen para abrir url, algunos no tiene su url y quiero que muestre un mensaje de que no cuenta con el pero no se como realizarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarte mejor? ¿quieres hacer eso al pulsar un botón o una imagen? Da más detalles

Comment: Con una UIImage que contiene los URL de la base de datos, pulsar la imagen y me mande a ellos

Comment: Un `UIImage` no puede contener ningún dato que no sea la imagen...

Comment: Oh, ¿entonces no se puede guardar un URL de un facebook o algo así como se ve en la imagen? ¿Tengo que crear un botón con el url entonces?

Comment: Tienes que crear un botón, y la acción de ese botón abrir la URL

Comment: Ok, eres el que siempre me anda ayudando gracias

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Swift puedes validar con isEmpty y mostrar un UIAlertView() :

```
if (textField.text.isEmpty) {
                let alert = UIAlertView()
                alert.title = "Error"
                alert.message = "No existe url definida"
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
                alert.show()
}
```

Usando Swift 2.0 , if:

```
if let urlImagen = textField.text where textField.text.isEmpty {
    // crea UIAlertView()
}
```

Swift 2.0, guard:

```
guard let urlImagen = textField.text where textField.text.isEmpty else {
    // crea UIAlertView()
    return
}
```

Para cargar una url de imagen dentro de un [UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/), este es un ejemplo:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.mydominio.com/myimagen.jpg") {
  if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
     imageURL.image = UIImage(data: data)
  }        
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda :D pero aparte de eso creo que no explique bien mi pregunta, no se como abrir los URL desde un UIImage y es lo que quiero realizar.

Comment: ok Brandon,agregue un ejemplo d como cargarlo, ese bloque de código lo puedes llamar cuando validas en realidad tienes un Url de imagen válido.

Comment: Si, eso si lo se hacer pero yo queria abrir un facebook dandole a la imagen

Comment: Brandon, acabo de ver agregaste una imagen, trata de realizar tus preguntas con más detalles para que sean respondidas eficientemente =)

Comment: Si, ya respondieron mi duda, gracias

Comment: perfecto Brando, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Muy simple... compruebas si el campo url de tu data esta vacio y de ser asi usa un UIAlertView, si quieres con un delegate = nil, algo asi:

```
if miUrl.isEmpty {
    let alert = UIAlertView("Aviso!!!", message: "Mmmm, no tengo url!", delegate: nil,
                            cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()
}else{
    //hacer algo
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda :D pero aparte de eso creo que no explique bien mi pregunta, no se como abrir los URL desde un UIImage y es lo que quiero realizar.